# why i got the error and foreachBatch in which jar or spark version?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to use the foreachBatch method in sparkstream but i got the error :Cannot resolve symbol foreachBatch
and check out the spark API,I still can't find this method

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.html

I want to know foreachBatch method in which jar or spark version ,THX,QAQ

```
test.writeStream.outputMode("update").option("checkpointLocation", chkp_es).foreachBatch
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreachBatch` method is avalable from version 2.4.0. You can use `foreach` method instead if suits your needs. You can refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter)